# How store count value from sql query in to a variable for creating a customerid according to the no of customers in the table?

Tags: java, sql, variables, count

I want to store the count value received into a variable count which then can be appended to a string to prepare a customer id but it is giving me the cursor invalid error. Please have a look below and help me out. thanks in advance. :)

```
    **package components;
    import java.awt.geom.GeneralPath;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    public class genrateid {

        public void generateid(){

    int count;


            try {
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:XE",
                        "system", "tiger");
                System.out.println("Connection Successfull");
                System.out.println(conn); 

                //--------------------------------------------------------------------
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                String query1= "select count(*) as customercount from customers";

                ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery(query1);
    count = rs.getInt(1);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            genrateid gen = new genrateid();
            gen.generateid();

        }
        }**


I am receiving the following error in  in eclipse IDE:
```

OUTPUT:

```
Connection Successfull
sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection@39b27b
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid cursor state
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLGetDataInteger(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getDataInteger(Unknown Source)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getInt(Unknown Source)
    at components.genrateid.generateid(genrateid.java:29)
    at components.genrateid.main(genrateid.java:43)
```

Comment: Why not just use an IDENTITY column?

Comment: Also: you shouldn't be using the JDBC/ODBC bridge. It's buggy and slow. Oracle has a very good pure (Type4) JDBC driver.

Comment: @Dems: Oracle does not have "IDENTITY" columns. He/She would need to use a sequence.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - What am I missing, how did you know this is for Oracle?

Comment: @Dems: it's the JDBC and the username/password. "XE" is typically used for OracleExpress and "scott/tiger" is one of Oracle's default accounts. Both together are a strong indicator for an Oracle installation.

Answer (score 0):

insert this line

```
if(rs.next())
```

before

```
  count = rs.getInt(1);
```

and you'll be good. But, as Dems said, consider using IDENTITY column (or because you are using Oracle - SEQUENCE)